# Bluetooth limitations

Tags: java, android

While using bluetooth to share files from one android mobile as server and many mobiles (20-30) can download files simultaneously from that server.
What are the limitation of bluetooth api in android ?
Is it possible ?

How do you prefer to do this? On bluetooth or via wifi ?
Thanks

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: SHOUT. SHOUT. LET IT ALL OUT!

Comment: Oops m not an Eglish man; don't know much english.....after your comment i came to know that "Writing in caps means shout" :P

Comment: shout = scream = talk using loud voice

Comment: Note that questions about our personal preferences do not belong here. You can still ask for the pros/cons of each.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have 7 slaves for a [bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) master, so if if you need 20-30 simultaneous connections this may not work. This is a bluetooth restriction, not Android.

Comment: hmmm thanks for your reply.... i had worked for past two days on this. is it possible to make a queue and then connect with 20 30 users ? kindly share your opnion. thnaks